# How to store datapoint that is unique but related to database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working on a small PHP/Javascript map application that is basically just pulling a bunch of location names and coordinate points from a MySQL database table and adding them to an HTML canvas. It's supposed to represent locations visited by a character in an ongoing collaborative story, so I'd like to be able to also have the map retrieve the character's position on the map at any given time and display this with a different icon.

The most obvious solution -- since the character, like the map locations, has a name and coordinates -- seems to be just including the character as their own row in the locations table as well, and having the map code recognize their unique information and display them differently. But since the character is not, in and of themselves, a location, storing them in the "locations" table seems weird. Creating a whole new table, "character", just for this one row seems like overkill though.

So I guess my more general question is what is a good way for PHP/MySQL to deal with unique data like this, that is related to existing tables but not closely enough. Do I keep this data in a text file and update that with PHP?

Comment: I don't see how a text file is any less weird than a table with a single row.  Is the character's location actually supposed to be persisted?  Or is it just something the application "knows" at any given time that it renders?

Comment: You have a point. :) The application would just need to know the location at the time it renders, the same way it retrieves the other map coordinates. I'm just curious if there's a best practice for this.

Comment: I'm still not clear... *"The application would just need to know the location at the time it renders."*  Is the application calculating this information live in some way, or does it need to pull this from some sort of data persistence?  If the former, then you don't need to put it in the database at all.  Just programmatically include it with the rest of the database results.  If the latter, a table to store this information is fine.  Single-record tables aren't uncommon.

Comment: It was indeed the latter (the persistence)...thanks for wading through my unclear explanation, and for your help! :) Much appreciated.

Comment: @David, care to make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing particularly "weird" about having a table which is intended to have only a single row.  Indeed, using a database for some of your data and a text file for other data would probably be a bit more weird.

Having a table also gives you the possibility of tracking character locations over time, if you ever need that information for any reason.  (Better to track it and not use it than need it and not have been tracking it.)

If the position of the character is calculated on the spot and doesn't need to be persisted then you can simply add it programmatically to the results from the database and it would be entirely transparent to both the database and the view.  But if it does need to be persisted, a table is probably the way to go.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! That's a good point about the over-time thing too; that hadn't occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a separate table for the character positions . . . over time.  It would have columns such as:

- Character id
- Location
- Date/time stamp

Eventually, you may want to have more than one character whose location can be shown over time.  You may have non-characters; in this case, you'll want to change the name of the table.

There is a big difference between the locations and the character positions.  The locations are static, at least once they are defined.  The character positions are time dependent.  They are a separate entity, and are best served by having their own table.